# Using vbs saving a .xlsx as a tab delimited .txt file

Tags: excel, vbscript, save-as, csv

I am simply opening a file, deleting two lines and changing the contents of cell a1 and then trying to save the excel file as a tab delimited text file. I have tried so many ways but everything is giving me a compilation reading "expected statement" error wherever there is a colon (:).

```
 Set ExcelObject = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 ExcelObject.visible = True
 ExcelObject.Workbooks.Open"c:\snowfall.xlsx",Default, False
 ExcelObject.sheets(1).Rows("1:2").Delete
 ExcelObject.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).value = "testing write function"
 ExcelObject.SaveAs Filename:=Activesheet.name, FileFormat:=xlText, _
```

the only line that has an error is the last one:

```
ExcelObject.SaveAs Filename:=Activesheet.name, FileFormat:=xlText, _
```

I have been banging my head against the wall for the last three days trying to get this to work :/

Comment: you have an _ at the end of that line so there is additional options set that you haven't shown......or that is what may be causing the issue....

Comment: `ExcelObject.SaveAs` is wrong, you save workbooks not the application itself. Also show the full code for SaveAs.... the issue might be there.

Comment: the short answer is replace `ExcelObject.SaveAs` with `ExcelObject.Sheets(1).SaveAs`

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors.

1. As mentioned in the comments, you save Workbooks, not the
   Excel.Application object. The calls to `.Sheets` need to reference
   the Workbook as well. The `.Open` method returns a reference to the
   Workbook - grab that for use below.
2. VBScript knows nothing about the
   built in Excel constants.  You need to supply the actual values that
   they represent in the enumeration.  For example, `xlText` is -4158.
3. VBScript doesn't support named argument syntax.  You'll need to pass them explicitly.
4. `ActiveSheet.Name` is going to return `snowfall.xlsx`.  You'll need to save the file with a `.txt` extension.

The end result should look more like this:

```
 Set ExcelObject = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 ExcelObject.Visible = True
 Set wb = ExcelObject.Workbooks.Open("c:\snowfall.xlsx")
 wb.Sheets(1).Rows("1:2").Delete
 wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "testing write function"
 wb.SaveAs "c:\snowfall.txt", -4158
```